# create a commit although no files have changed

Tags: git, starteam

I am writing a porting tool to convert old [Borland StarTeam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarTeam) repositories to [git](https://git-scm.com/). Sometimes, though, several revisions (StarTeams counterpart to a commit in git) are identical, except for their labels.

Each revision should map to a single commit, which seems not to be possible in git, when no files differ between two adjacent commits.
Currently I see two options getting this done:

1. Write all revision labels into a single commit's message. Not the way my boss wants it to be.
2. Create and change a dummy file, showing git something has changed. Not the nice way.

Is there any other, more elegant solution?

Comment: `git commit --allow-empty`  should work

Comment: Thanks, `--allow-empty` is exactly what I needed.

Comment: cool, but this goes to be duplicated :)

Comment: Why would you add revision labels to a commit message? You could instead create a tag for each revision label and add all those tags to the commit. Tag is the Git equivalent for labels used by many other version control systems and probably more appropriate here than a bunch of empty commits.